# Is it possible to use NOTIFY on postgresql without triggering a commit in the write ahead log?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, socket.io

I have been using socket.io via PostgreSQL https://socket.io/docs/v4/postgres-adapter/ (which uses pg node module on with pool.query ). This has some heartbeat implemented. The problem is that the NOTIFY triggers a rather empty commit in the write ahead log every second.

Can the commit be avoided?

Comment: The commit actually spins up the hard disk. This is actually my problem: https://github.com/immich-app/immich/discussions/8009

Comment: 1) Notifications are stored in a queue  on disk in pg_notify/. 2) A notification does not happen until a commit occurs per [Notify](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is unfortunate, but I don't think it can be avoided. See the source of `PreCommit_Notify()`:

```c
        /*
         * Make sure that we have an XID assigned to the current transaction.
         * GetCurrentTransactionId is cheap if we already have an XID, but not
         * so cheap if we don't, and we'd prefer not to do that work while
         * holding NotifyQueueLock.
         */
        (void) GetCurrentTransactionId();

        /*
         * Serialize writers by acquiring a special lock that we hold till
         * after commit.  This ensures that queue entries appear in commit
         * order, and in particular that there are never uncommitted queue
         * entries ahead of committed ones, so an uncommitted transaction
         * can't block delivery of deliverable notifications.
         *
         * We use a heavyweight lock so that it'll automatically be released
         * after either commit or abort.  This also allows deadlocks to be
         * detected, though really a deadlock shouldn't be possible here.
         *
         * The lock is on "database 0", which is pretty ugly but it doesn't
         * seem worth inventing a special locktag category just for this.
         * (Historical note: before PG 9.0, a similar lock on "database 0" was
         * used by the flatfiles mechanism.)
         */
        LockSharedObject(DatabaseRelationId, InvalidOid, 0,
                         AccessExclusiveLock);
```

The transaction ID is needed for the lock, and these two cause the WAL flush that you observe.

I don't know what you are using `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` for, but perhaps some other way of inter-process communication could do the trick, for example [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS).

Comment: What irritated was the quote from async.c "..., and there is no need for WAL support or fsync'ing." (https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/605062227fdc8331f2ffa0f60e7a8724b6e56480/src/backend/commands/async.c#L37). Regarding the "use case" currently the proble is quite generally publish/subscribe the socket.io postgres backend (https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-postgres-adapter/blob/e5e3b6293cfe6da8800de5a139f5ef5c4f25af48/lib/index.ts#L261). Would be great to have a advisory lock example for pubsub.

Comment: The comment probably means that `NOTIFY` as such doesn't have to be persisted. The lock on "database 0" is just taken to serialize notifications, and that causes a transaction ID to be consumed and a WAL write. The comment should probably be improved. As to the code, that is written in a language I don't speak.